autoencoder_kmeans from raw MNIST data
As a learning exercise I am trying to implement the code at:
https://github.com/tschechlovdev/AutoEncoder_KMeans/blob/main/AutoEncoder_KMeans_MNIST.ipynb
but I would like to use my own dataset. Their code uses the MNIST dataset as follows:
    from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
    from torch.utils.data import ConcatDataset
    from torchvision import transforms
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),])
    trainset = MNIST('./', download=True,train=True,transform=transform)
    testset = MNIST('./', download=True,train=False,transform=transform)
    dataset = ConcatDataset([trainset, testset])
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=256, shuffle=True,num_workers=10)


Alternatively, I would like to import the raw mnist datafiles as implemented in
https://tjgokken.com/converting-mnist-data-to-csv-or-individual-files-using-python
which generates the mnist_train/test data as csv files.
Unfortunately, I have not successfully figured out how to use this raw data as a replacement
for the MNIST data (as loaded above).
My logic is that if the raw mnist data can be successfully loaded into the autoencoder_kmeans script,
I should also be able to use my own dataset for analysis.
If successful, I would also need to implement the transform steps as above.
In other words how can I avoid the torch utilities and use the raw data, and reproduce their results.
Thanks in advance for any help,
David
There are other autoencoder scripts based on kmeans clustering. The one selected above provides
a wide selection of definitions appropriate for this task. However, other code would be greatly appreciated.
In the listing of related questions, Making your own set of MNIST data (identical to MNIST format) provides an alternative means to generate the raw data, but morphing
into the autoencoder_kmeans code is still unanswered.
